# Can I say "something another"?

Tags: adjectives

In the following example sentence:

> You must choose something else.

Can I say it with the following:

> You must choose something another.

I was told that *something another* is not correct, but not sure about the reason.

Or more generally, does *another* have to be put before the noun, or is it fine to put after a noun but not after some specific nouns like *something*?

Comment: You may have misheard "something or other" as "something another".  "Something or other" is an idiom that means "something" but implies that you don't care what it is or it's unimportant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does another have to be put before the noun?

Yes. When "another" is functioning as an adjective, the rules are the same as for most other adjectives: "another angle", "another time", "another piece of pie".

When "another" is functioning as a pronoun, it's stand-alone: "one copy for her and another for him." "in one way or another"

The example sentence could be written as follows:

> You must choose another one.
>
> You must choose another.